# ListBox - como mostrar nome completo do produto e trazer outra coluna de valores

Tags: c#, txt, listbox

Tenho este `ListBox`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando carregado ele usa um `txt file` ficando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Código para carregar a `ListBox`:

```
private void frmOrdemServico_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] d = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\willian\\Downloads\\dbProdutos.txt");
        foreach (var line in d)
        {
            string[] produtos = line.Split(' ');
            lbProdutos.Items.Add(produtos[0]);
        }
    }
```

Tenho 2 problemas:

> **1º** Os nomes dos produtos não estão completos porque onde tem espaço é corta: exemplo: Sabão Líquido, fica: Sabão só. **[resolvido]**
>
> **2º** Não sei como faço para trazer em outra coluna dentro do ListBox os valores dos produtos, pois pretendo utiliza-los. **[resolvido]**

Meu arquivo `txt` está com está forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*desconsidere os dados só ligue para estrutura*

> Observação.: Li um pouco na internet sobre o ListView porém não
> consegui implementá-lo, pois não conseguia passar dados de um lado
> para outro etc. E trazer as duas colunas enfim..

Comment: Parece que o seu separador de campos é o `-`, logo fazer `Split` por `-` já resolveria o problema de cortar as palavras

Comment: Verdade, resolvido este problema, nem reparei nisso, estava dando espaço, porque pensei que ele pegava o espaço das palavras..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fins de conhecimento, eu consegui implementar usando o `ListBox` também, desta forma:

```
private void frmOrdemServico_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            string[] lineOfContents = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\willian\\Downloads\\dbClientes.txt");
            cbClientes.Items.Clear(); // limpar para não duplicar valores
            foreach (var line in lineOfContents)
            {
                string[] nomes = line.Split(',');
                cbClientes.Items.Add(nomes[0]);
            }

            string[] d = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\willian\\Downloads\\dbProdutos.txt");
            foreach (var line in d)
            {
                string[] produtos = line.Split(';');
                lbProdutos.Items.Add(produtos[0] + " R$" + Convert.ToDouble(produtos[1]));
            }
        }
```

Linha alterada: `lbProdutos.Items.Add(produtos[0] + " R$" + Convert.ToDouble(produtos[1]));`

Desta maneira consegui trazer o outro valor que estava no `txt file`.

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem a opção de usar `ListView`, então acho melhor usá-lo nesse caso.

O código abaixo mostra como você pode mover itens de um `listview` para outro.

Eu deixei a opção `MultiSelect = true` para permitir a movimentação de vários itens entre os ListViews.

```
void frmOrdemServico_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lvwProdutos.Columns.Add("Produto",100,HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    lvwProdutos.Columns.Add("Valor",60,HorizontalAlignment.Right);
    lvwProdutos.View = View.Details;
    lvwProdutos.FullRowSelect = true;
    lvwProdutos.MultiSelect = true;

    lvwProdutosUsados.Columns.Add("Produto",100,HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    lvwProdutosUsados.Columns.Add("Valor",60,HorizontalAlignment.Right);
    lvwProdutosUsados.View = View.Details;
    lvwProdutosUsados.FullRowSelect = true;
    lvwProdutosUsados.MultiSelect = true;

    string[] d = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\desenv\dbProdutos.txt");
    foreach (var line in d)
    {
        string[] produtos = line.Split('-');

        var item = new ListViewItem();
        item.Text = produtos[0];
        item.SubItems.Add(produtos[1]);

        lvwProdutos.Items.Add(item);
    }
}


void btnAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in lvwProdutos.SelectedItems)
    {               
        lvwProdutos.Items.Remove(item);
        lvwProdutosUsados.Items.Add(item);
    }   
}


void btnRemover_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in lvwProdutosUsados.SelectedItems)
    {               
        lvwProdutosUsados.Items.Remove(item);
        lvwProdutos.Items.Add(item);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Obrigado cara, era isso mesmo que precisava, eu até tinha conseguido com o `ListBox` porém não vou conseguir fazer uma outra implementação que preciso.. Porque preciso que quando vá para o outro `ListView` chame um forms com um campo txt `quantidade` e multiplique, alias se souber isso também xD me ajuda já. Obrigado!!

Answer (score -1):

Tente usar o propriedade valueMember do listBox:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember(v=vs.110).aspx