# ListBox - Multiplicar valores e passar para outro Listbox

Tags: c#, txt, listbox

Tenho 2 ListBox.

Quando eu passar um valor para o outro ListBox é aberto uma tela para digitar a quantidade que quero daquele produto.

Dito isso, irá pegar a quantidade * valor e mostrar no outro ListBox.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código que carrega o listBox:

```
private void frmOrdemServico_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            string[] lineOfContents = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\willian\\Downloads\\dbClientes.txt");
            cbClientes.Items.Clear(); // limpar para não duplicar valores
            foreach (var line in lineOfContents)
            {
                string[] nomes = line.Split(',');
                cbClientes.Items.Add(nomes[0]);
            }
               // Preencher ListBox
            string[] d = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\willian\\Downloads\\dbProdutos.txt");
            foreach (var line in d)
            {
                string[] produtos = line.Split(';');
                lbProdutos.Items.Add(produtos[0] + " R$" + Convert.ToDouble(produtos[1]));
            }
        }
```

Eu consigo fazer multiplicar somente se fizer isso, nesta linha:

`lbProdutos.Items.Add(produtos[0] + " R$" + Convert.ToDouble(produtos[1])*2);`

Mas não consigo fazer quando eu passo o valor por este forms.

Código para passar os produtos para direita:

```
private void btnIr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmQuantidade qntd = new frmQuantidade();
            qntd.ShowDialog();


            if (lbProdutos.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Você não selecionou nenhum produto para adicionar");
            }
            else
            {
                lbProdutosUsando.Items.Add(lbProdutos.SelectedItem);
                lbProdutos.Items.Remove(lbProdutos.SelectedItem);
            }
        }
```

Código para passar os produtos para esquerda:

```
private void btnVoltar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lbProdutosUsando.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Você não selecionou nenhum produto para remover");
            }
            else
            {
                lbProdutos.Items.Add(lbProdutosUsando.SelectedItem);
                lbProdutosUsando.Items.Remove(lbProdutosUsando.SelectedItem);
            }
        }
```

Neste outro tópico que fiz uma pessoa respondeu usando o ListView, ficou OK mas fico na mesma situação que o ListBox. 
[ListBox - como mostrar nome completo do produto e trazer outra coluna de valores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/250170/listbox-como-mostrar-nome-completo-do-produto-e-trazer-outra-coluna-de-valores)

**UPDATE**

Acredito que eu tenha feito o que o @Fernando disse na resposta dele, porém irei ter este erro conforme imagem abaixo, pois o valor do produto está concatenado a sua descrição, logo se eu passo para double dará erro, e agora?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Alterei o código da minha resposta para retirar o valor unitário da string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, você precisa criar uma propriedade no form `frmQuantidade` para que o form chamador possa  ter acesso à quantidade que foi digitada pelo usuário.

A implementação da propriedade `Qtde` pode ser feita da seguinte forma em `frmQuantidade`:

```
public partial class frmQuantidade : Form
{
    public frmQuantidade()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public double Qtde {get; set;}

    void btnGravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Qtde = Double.Parse(txtQtde.Text);
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Depois, no método `btnIr_Click` do form chamador, você poderá fazer o seguinte:

```
private void btnIr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     frmQuantidade qntd = new frmQuantidade();
     qntd.ShowDialog();   

     if (lbProdutos.SelectedItem == null)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Você não selecionou nenhum produto para adicionar");
     }
     else
     {
         //parser para retirar a descrição e o valor unitário de lbProdutos.SelectedItem
         int divisor = lbProdutos.SelectedItem.ToString().IndexOf("R$");
         string descricao = lbProdutos.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(0,divisor).Trim();
         double ValorUnitario = double.Parse( lbProdutos.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(divisor+2) );

         double valorTotal = valorUnitario * qntd.Qtde;

         //adicionar novo item com o valor total
         lbProdutosUsando.Items.Add(descricao + " R$ " + valorTotal .ToString());

         lbProdutos.Items.Remove(lbProdutos.SelectedItem);
     }
}
```

Eu ainda acho que usar o `ListView` será a melhor solução para o seu caso porque você poderá colocar na lista do lado direito as colunas com o nome do produto, o valor unitário, a quantidade e o valor total.

Comment: Obrigado @Fernando, era isso que precisava, irei utilizar da mesma forma que fez para percorrer todo o listbox e pegar todos os valores e jogar num textbox, agora que vi como você separa o "R$", agradeço mais uma vez.